Creating a dynamic grading table
My goal is to create a dynamic grading table like this:

The table reads as follows.you would get grade 15 if you either had 50, 49 or 48 points, and grade 14 if you scored 47 points.
For that I am trying to create a command that works like
\grading{15,14,...,1,0}{0.95,0.9,...,0.2,0}{50}{Points}{Grade}
that takes as input a list of possible grades, the percentages necessary to achieve a particular grade, the total number of points and the denominations for the points and grades. The first list basically should have minimal restrictions to its content, just a comma seperated list of numbers or letters (or maybe even graphics? That's certainly not a necessity). The second list needs to be of equal length as the first and contains decimals representing the corresponging percentages.
The idea is that the total number of points is calculated by the exam package and this table will be automatically created.
I don't really have good understanding of latex or expl3, so here is where I am sofar:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xintexpr}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand{\upto}{\raisebox{0.0em}{$|$}}
\begin{document}
\def\gradeslist{F,E,D,C,B,A}
\def\gradinglist{0,0.2,0.5,0.7,0.8,0.9}
\def\points{100}
\begin{table}[h]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{r|*{17}{Y}}
\toprule
  Grade: & \xintFor #1 in \gradeslist \do {\xintifForFirst{#1}{& #1} } \\\hline
  & \xintFor #1 in \gradinglist \do {\xintifForFirst{\xinticeil{\xinteval{#1*\points}}}{& \xinticeil{\xinteval{#1*\points}}}}\\
  
  Points:  \xintFor #1 in \gradinglist \do{&\upto}\\
  
   \xintFor #1 in \gradinglist \do {\xintifForFirst{}{& \xinticeil{\xinteval{#1*\points-1}}}}&\points\\\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}

which gives me

This is fantastic and almost exactly what I want (exept for the denominations, of course). Now here is my problem. Sometimes only one particular point leads to a certain grade and it seems silly to give a range of points for that. So I want the following: If the values of the 2nd and 4th row of a particular coloumn coincide, I want those values not displayed and instead want \upto to be replaced by said value.
So, with everything the same except for the maximum number of points to 25, \grading{15,14,...,1,0}{0.95,0.9,...,0.2,0}{50}{Points}{Grade}
should generate this table:

Unfortunately getting conditionals into my code with xint has not been a kind adventure for me and I kind of grew tired of always trying new things, not understanding why they don't work. I clearly lack the knowledge to produce what I want, so any help would be appreciated.

it isn't clear to me what the range of possibilities is here. you say the second thing input will be percentages, but the example input you give are not percentages (unless you have extremely low standards or set extremely difficult questions!). you also use ... syntax in your sample input, but how should this go? are the steps between grades always equal in your world? (in mine, they are not!) are there other possible grade formats e.g. Greek letters (used when I was an undergrad), +, -, Pass. Fail ... ? you've shown 2 scales: A to F (no U?) and 0 to 15. other formats?

Thank you for your comment, I agree this part might not have been well explained in my post. The input are percentages, but in the result we see the absolute number of points necessary to achieve a particular grade. I definitely would need a solution which allows + and -.

But your second argument in the sample input is 0.95,0.9,...,20,0. does nobody score above 20%? and how are the dots to be completed? there's no obvious sequence here: 0.95 then down to 0.9 then something-something-something and we're suddenly at 20 and down to 0. how did we end up at 20 if we started at 0.95 and went down?

The 20 collides of course with my explanation and with the code of the mwe I posted, it's a typo.

Using tabularray package and a bit of expl3 the following code seems promising.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l__ME_table_tl

\NewDocumentCommand { \grading } { m m m m m }
  {
    % store upper value for next grade
    \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { #3 }

    % build a tokenlist with table content
    % expand the tokenlist later in tblr environment
    \tl_set:Nn \l__ME_table_tl { #4: }

    % mapping over grades list and store them in the tokenlist
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
      { \tl_put_right:Nn \l__ME_table_tl { & ##1 } }

    % start new line in table
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__ME_table_tl { \\ #5: }

    % mapping over decimal values
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
      {
        % calculate lower value
        \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { ceil ( ##1 * #3 ) }
        \tl_put_right:Ne \l__ME_table_tl
          {
            & \fp_compare:nTF
                { \l_tmpa_fp = \l_tmpa_int }
                % same upper/lower value
                { \fp_use:N \l_tmpa_fp }
                % different upper/lower value
                {
                  \fp_use:N \l_tmpa_fp
                  \par$|$\par
                  \int_use:N \l_tmpa_int
                }
          }
        % store upper value for next grade
        \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { \fp_use:N \l_tmpa_fp - 1 }
      }

    % typeset table and expand tokenlist
    \begin{tblr}[expand=\l__ME_table_tl]
      {
        hlines , vlines , rowspec = {*{2}{Q[m]}} ,
        colspec = {l*{\clist_count:n{#1}}{X[c]}}
      }
      \l__ME_table_tl
    \end{tblr}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\grading
  {15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0}
  {0.95,0.9,0.85,0.8,0.75,0.7,0.65,0.6,0.55,0.5,0.45,0.4,0.33,0.27,0.2,0}
  {25}{Grade}{Points}

\end{document}



weird expl3 magic, exactly what I was hoping for. Looks indeed promising. I tried it and in my larger document it produced a weird result. I isolated the problem: If you add usepackage{minted} to your code, both rows will be depicted next to each other. Any idea what might be the reason for this? Unfortunately I am very much reliant on the minted package.

Oops, your right. Seems like the problem is within the line \tl_put_right:Ne \l__ME_table_tl { \\ #5: } because of expansion of the argument (Ne). But expanding the argument isn't necessary here, so a simple \tl_put_right:Nn is enough. Problem is then fixed for me; edited the code.

Not only did you provide the a fantastic solution, you also took the time to comment your code. At some point I want to take the time to make sure I understand it, and your comments surely will be of help.

Without your complex calculation of grade ranges you may write your grade table directly using tblr of tabularray package as follows:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{ colspec = {r|*{6}{Q[c,m, wd=2em]}}}
    \toprule
Grade:  &   F           &   E           &   D   &   C           &   B           &   A           \\
    \midrule
Points: & {0\\$|$\\19}  & {20\\$|$\\49} &   50  & {70\\$|$\\79} & {80\\$|$\\89} & {90\\$|$\\100} \\
   \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{center}
\end{document}



+1. I think the "A" range should start at 90, not 9. Moreover, the "D" column should be a range (50-69), not a point.

I don't mean to be rude and I'm sure I'm missing something. How does this provide anything that I was looking for? I already know how to generate this particular table and even posted a code to generate it. Doing this manually for every test is exactly what I'm looking to automate.

@Mico, corrected now. Thank you very much for pointing me to this error.

@M.E., result of my suggestion gives what you like to have on the end. Of course it not contain you  tangled approach.  You may to define it as newcommand (do you have at each test different grading?) and use at each test.

how would it be possible to generate a table with a different number of rows? i would have to manually calculate all the points from the percentages and manually create the table afterwords. i know my code was convoluted because i hacked it together but your answer is basically just saying how you can create a table in latex.

ty for spending your time for typing out a possible solution though
